# How to cancel the Linux LVM configuration?

Tags: partitioning, fedora, lvm

I have installed Fedora 12. By default it is installed with logical volume configuration. Now I need to cancel the LVM and use simple flat partitions. My main concern now is not to lose my data.
Any help?

**Update:**

I am trying to cancel LVM configuration to be able to mount my volumes from other Linux distros that do not support LVM by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this. There's also usually no good reason to do so. If you were to explain *why* you want this (perhaps in another question) then someone may be able to help you find a solution.

Comment: Because my target machine will not benefit from the LVM and it would be easier for me to administrate and apply hacks

Comment: Did you have any particular hacks in mind?

Comment: Actually, my hard disk lives in a .vdi virtual hard disk. I need to mount it on a real machine. I could find a solution to this by mounting it as a loop device considering some calculated offset. I stuck at calculating the sector offset for my root logical volume because of the 'Linux LVM' partition type while I know what to do if it were a normal 'Extended Partition'

Comment: @mmo, use kpartx: http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2008-June/msg00045.html